# How is Grover's algorithm used to estimate the mean and median of a set of numbers?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, grovers-algorithm

On the [Wikipedia page for Grover's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm), it is mentioned that:

*"Grover's algorithm can also be used for estimating the mean and median of a set of numbers"*

So far I only knew how it can be used to search a database. But not sure how to implement that technique to estimate the mean and median of a set of numbers. Moreover, there's no citation (as far as I noticed) on that page which explains the technique.

Comment: Either if you choose to answer your own question, or for whoever chooses take the task for themselves, this link looks like a great place to start [How to Use Grover’s Algorithm to Find the Average (a.k.a Mean, Integral) of a Weirdo Function](https://qbnets.wordpress.com/2013/09/28/how-to-use-grovers-algorithm-to-find-the-average-a-k-a-mean-integral-of-a-weirdo-function/)

Comment: I think the relevant paper is ["An optimal quantum algorithm to approximate the mean and its application for approximating the median of a set of points over an arbitrary distance" by Brassard et al](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.4267).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The idea for estimating the mean is roughly as follows:

- For any $f(x)$ that gives outputs in the reals, define a rescaled $F(x)$ that gives outputs in the range 0 to 1. We aim to estimate the mean of $F(x)$.
- Define a unitary $U_a$ whose operation is $$U_a:|0\rangle|0\rangle\mapsto\frac{1}{2^{n/2}}\sum_x|x\rangle(\sqrt{1-F(x)}|0\rangle+\sqrt{F(x)}|1\rangle).$$ It is important to note that this unitary is easily implemented. You start with a Hadamard transform on the first register, perform a computation of $f(x)$ on an ancilla register, use this to implement a controlled-rotation of the second register, and then uncompute the ancilla register.
- Define the unitary $G=U_a (\mathbb{I}-2|0\rangle\langle 0|\otimes |0\rangle\langle 0|)U_a^\dagger \mathbb{I}\otimes Z$.
- Starting from a state $U_a|0\rangle|0\rangle$, use $G$ much like you would use the Grover iterator to estimate the number of solutions to a search problem.

The main bulk of this algorithm is amplitude amplification, as described [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0005055). The main idea is that you can define two states
$$
|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_x F(x)}}\sum_x\sqrt{F(x)}|x\rangle|1\rangle \qquad |\psi^\perp\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_x 1-F(x)}}\sum_x\sqrt{1-F(x)}|x\rangle|0\rangle,
$$
and this defines a subspace for the evolution. The initial state is $U_a|0\rangle|0\rangle=(\sqrt{\sum_x F(x)}|\psi\rangle+\sqrt{\sum_x 1-F(x)}|\psi^\perp\rangle)2^{-n/2}$. The amplitude of the $|\psi\rangle$ term clearly contains the information about the mean of $F(x)$, if we could just estimate it. You could just repeatedly prepare this state and measure the probability of getting a $|1\rangle$ on the second register, but Grover's search gives you a quadratic improvement. If you compare to the way Grover's is usually set up, the amplitude of this $|\psi\rangle$ which you can 'mark' (in this case by applying $\mathbb{I}\otimes Z$) would be $\sqrt{\frac{m}{2^n}}$ where $m$ is the number of solutions.

Incidentally, this is interesting to compare to the "power of one clean qubit", also known as DQC1. There, if you apply $U_a$ to $\frac{\mathbb{I}}{2^n}\otimes|0\rangle\langle 0|$, the probability of getting the 1 answer is just the same as the non-accelerated version, and gives you an estimate of the mean.

---

For the median, it can [apparently](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.4267) be defined as the value $z$ that minimises
$$
\sum_x|f(x)-f(z)|.
$$
There are two steps here. The first is to realise that the function we're trying to minimise over is basically just a mean. Then the second step is to use a [minimisation algorithm](http://xxx.lanl.gov/abs/quant-ph/9607014) which can also be accelerated by a Grover search. The idea here is to use a Grover's search, and mark all items for which the function evaluation gives a value less than some threshold $T$. You can estimate the number of inputs $x$ that give $f(x)\leq T$, then repeat for a different $T$ until you localise the minimum value sufficiently.

Of course, I am skipping over some details of precise running times, error estimates etc.

Comment: Do you need to first run Grover's algorithm a logarithmic number of times to calculate the min and max value of the function before you can perform the rescaling in step 1?

Comment: @tparker That probably depends. Often it's asumed that you know enough about the function F to be able to bound its possible values.