# Does HHL implementation require a priori eigendecomposition?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, hhl-algorithm

I am interested in HHL algorithm and despite all the problems related to current technologies, I am trying to understand how it has to be implemented.

I have seen from these two available circuits  ([arXiv:1804.03719](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.03719), [arXiv:1811.01726](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.01726)) that when you define a circuit it is necessary to apply a certain rotation of the ancilla qubit based on the eigenvalues. For what I understood from the original paper, the algorithm "extracts" the information about eigenvalues using the quantum phase estimation algorithm but this part is missing in the circuits.

My doubt is if I have to decompose my matrix to find eigenvalues I lose the possible advantage derived from the algorithm; is that correct?

Comment: **Related:** [HHL algorithm — why isn't the required knowledge on eigenspectrum a major drawback?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2622), [Efficiently performing controlled rotations in HHL](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4415/efficiently-performing-controlled-rotations-in-hhl) & [Quantum phase estimation and HHL algorithm - knowledge of eigenvalues required?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2604).

Comment: Hi Macalcubo!  What is your application to which you are trying to gain an advantage?  Can you describe elements in your $N\times N$ matrix $A$ easily enough with quantum gates?  Is $A$ sparse enough?  Can you prepare your input vector $\vec b$ efficiently, say, for example, as a uniform superposition over all $N$ states?  Is it OK to sample $\vec x$?

Comment: Hi Mark! I am just trying to estimate a linear model using the HHL, which is the same thing I saw in the papers. In the end, my idea would be to estimate a GLM using matrix inversion, but first I want to get an implementation of  HHL to perform simulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am learning it right now, so I can only give a partially satisfying answer. Nobody answered so far, so I'll give you the best I know waiting for somebody to give a more detailed answer.

I suggest you have a look at the qiskit book, which has a [simple tutorial](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-applications/hhl_tutorial.html#2.-The-HHL-algorithm) that I found super useful. They literally say that you don't have to compute the eigenvalues. This is because a matrix $A$ that is $N\times N$ can have up to $N$ distinct eigenvalues and therefore computing them will take at least $O(N)$ time, which means the exponential advantage is lost.

In general, I think the idea is that when you perform a QPE you have a state that encodes the values of the eigenvalues, but you cannot access them. In a similar way, you cannot directly access the solution vector. Thus, the QC can perform a controlled rotation based on the value of those eigenvectors because they are encoded in a quantum state.