# In the quantum mean computation circuit, how to apply the controlled rotation to the extra qubit?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, amplitude-amplification

I'm trying to implement quantum mean computation via amplitude estimation, as suggested in Example 8.3.5 in Kaye, LaFlamme, Mosca. I wonder about the actual circuit to accomplish this. This previous [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1967/how-is-grovers-algorithm-used-to-estimate-the-mean-and-median-of-a-set-of-numbe/1982#1982) suggested to construct an operator $U_a$ for a (normalized) $F(x)$:

$$
U_a:|0\rangle|0\rangle\mapsto
\frac{1}{2^{n/2}}
    \sum_x|x\rangle(\sqrt{1-F(x)}|0\rangle+\sqrt{F(x)}|1\rangle).
$$

> It is important to note that this unitary is easily implemented. You
> start with a Hadamard transform on the first register, perform a
> computation of f(x)  on an ancilla register, use this to implement a
> controlled-rotation of the second register, and then uncompute the
> ancilla register.

I have trouble implementing this. It is clear that in the formula above the first $|0\rangle$ is the multi-qubit state $|00...0\rangle$ which I have to put in equal superposition with $H^{\otimes n}$. I call the second $|0\rangle$ the 'extra' qubit.

For each state $x$, I compute $v = F(x)$. So if my state vector is $[0.1026, 0.2052, 0.3078, 0.9234]$ then I compute, for example, $F(0) = v = 0.1026$. I rotate an ancilla via $2 R_y(\arcsin(v))$. So far, so good.

The next step is confusing. How do I apply the controlled rotation of the extra qubit? Just having something like a Controlled-Not from the ancilla to the extra qubit will not work and just leave the state in an equal superposition. But even have a fully controlled rotation, controlled by the bit patterns of $x$ doesn't seem to be working?

Is there perhaps a pointer to a working implementation? (Thx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self-answer: This is actually a bit simpler than I thought. For two qubits (and this can be easily generalized to more qubits), the circuit would have to look like the following, where the $\theta_i$ corresponding to the results of calls to $F(x_i)$ as $\theta_i = 2 \arcsin(F(x_i))$:
[image]

With this circuit one can estimate the mean (of the $F(x_i)$) by measuring the probability of the extra qubit to be in state $|1\rangle$. Expressing the circuit as a single big-matrix operator would allow amplitude estimation to find the same results.

I've put a working version in Python ([here](https://github.com/qcc4cp/qcc/blob/main/src/quantum_mean.py)).